# Paging with multiple filter in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I have to develop a search result page where each page will have 12 records along with multiple filter criteria.

```
I have applied the pagination and it works until any filter is applied.

I have uploaded my code to  plnkr
```

Comment: Here is pnkr ** https://plnkr.co/edit/tXMNFiiz6Em6gl47DRMW?p=preview**

Comment: The plunk doesn't seem to work. There is some error

Comment: I have got my answer thanks